# How to train deep learning model, if one class has large data compared to other classes

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

I am using keras for a text to speech project , and for this project I have almost 1000 labeled data.
since the sounds length in dataset are different , I resized all of them to the maximum length.
so most of my data is somthing like this now : 
(this is one sample of dataset)

[image: this is the image]

as you see more than half of it is empty ( zero )
now my problem is that sinece more than half of data has one class it is over fitting on that class and my the prediction is just an empty string.

how can I handle this kind of data ?

Comment: Usually you tackle this with sample weighting, in [Is it good to normalization/standardization data having large number of features with zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45370442/1782792) I put one possible rule for that.

Answer (score 1):

You have different way to handle this :

- Undersample the major class : delete a random sample of this class in order to make the two class even
- Oversample the minor class : You can try to duplicate some sample of this class, but that can lead to overfitting
- Oversample with synthetic data : Explore if there is a way to create completly new exemples by using existing data distibutions

Comment: actually in my case classes are alphabet letters , and in each sample I have almost all of them (ex. in the picture in the question  , so I can't delete anything to make balance.